# PHP server says it has no Supported Ciphers for mcrypt

Tags: php, mcrypt

We are configuring a PHP server currently, and when we run

```
phpinfo();
```

we see that mcrypt is included in the list of available modules, but it says "NONE" for both Supported ciphers and Supported modes.  A quick search in google returned little or no useful information.  Any insights or help would be appreciated!

Comment: You should provide more information relating to how PHP was installed, where it was obtainined from, what OS you are running etc.

Comment: OS is Slackware. Apache and PHP were both compiled/installed from source with the appropriate compile flags set.  Oddly enough the problem went away with a restart to apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggests you have the mcrypt support compiled into your version of PHP but the modules are not loaded or available.

For example on Linux you would need to install the php-mcrypt (or php5-mcrypt on Ubuntu) package.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  The problem seems to have gone away with a restart to Apache.  I don't remember changing anything before the restart, but that means virtually nothing.